# Why can't I access RouteData outside of Controller actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to access the ID created in RouteConfig in my HomeController using

```
var id = RouteData.Values["id"];
```

However, this line of code doesn't work outside of an action. Why is this? I can't even define publicly id and then initialise it in the action.

Is there a significant reason as to why I can't do this? If not, is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: why would you access a route value outside of the route?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? I think overriding `OnActionExecuting` for base controller class (assumed the action method used in derived controller with a base class) with `ActionExecutingContext` can retrieve the `RouteData` value.

Comment: You don't have access to your request context outside of controller. That's propably why you can't achieve that.This link can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846869/why-is-it-so-hard-to-get-route-values-outside-controller-context

Comment: @ElmerDantas If I had 10 values that I wanted to pass through the home controller, instead of writing 10 lines of code in each action, I wanted to write this in a function and call it in every action. I'm new to MVC so there may be a much better way of doing this? I'm probably confusing myself.

Comment: @JessicaWard check the link provided by Frix and see why you shouldn't follow this thought. Regards.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Thanks! It answered my question! Is there a way to mark this question as solved now?

Comment: @JessicaWard there is not need. I'll mark as duplicated and everything is fine. Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it so hard to get route values outside controller context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846869/why-is-it-so-hard-to-get-route-values-outside-controller-context)

Comment: @ElmerDantas Ok, thanks for your help!