# base api controller get route c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
[Route("api/advertisement/{brandID}/{advertisementID}")]
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public string AdvertisementID { get; private set; }
    public int BrandID { get; private set; }
    public BaseReportRepository ReportRepository { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        var routeData = controllerContext.RouteData;

        this.AdvertisementID = routeData.Values["advertisementID"].ToString();
        this.BrandID = (int)routeData.Values["brandID"];

        this.ReportRepository = RepositoryFactory
            .CreateRepository(this.BrandID)
            .ReportRepository;
    }
}
```

why can not get the router data `brandID`

Comment: what do you have actually in that varaible null or empty string?

Comment: Also how do you call it? the URL you use.

Comment: @Prashant Pretty sure `ApiController`'s `Initialize` method doesn't have an override including `brandID` and `advertismentID`.

Comment: get router data value "MS_SubRoutes""

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846869/why-is-it-so-hard-to-get-route-values-outside-controller-context) seems relevant.

Comment: I hope **BaseApiController** to Implementation ReportRepository then inherit the BaseApiController can call ReportRepository

Comment: There are other ways to achieve my above problem

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
IHttpRouteData requestRouteData = controllerContext.Request.GetRouteData();
IEnumerable<IHttpRouteData> subroutes = (IEnumerable<IHttpRouteData>)requestRouteData.Values["MS_SubRoutes"];
IHttpRouteData routeData = subroutes.FirstOrDefault();
if (routeData != null)
{
    this.AdvertisementID = routeData.Values["advertisementID"].ToString();
    this.BrandID = int.Parse(routeData.Values["brandID"].ToString());
}
```

You should also constrain your brandID parameter:

```
[Route("api/advertisement/{brandID:int}/{advertisementID}")]
```

If you’re traversing the route collection in any way (e.g. in a ControllerSelector) it is important to understand where these routes actually are. When you use attribute routing, all the route attributes get added to a common route without a name. This is a special route that is an instance of an internal class called RouteCollectionRoute. 
This route has a collection of sub-routes that you can query for that includes *all* the attribute routes.